# Matching a expression from userinput in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I want to match number-number expression.I want to get input from textField, and need to format in way that,i can use that two numbers
How can i do this, by using regular expression or something else. Please give me a suggestion. User input. Number-Number. I have to filter out. number, number as Integer. Also i have to check whether user entered anything wrong in textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use NSRegularExpression,

```
NSString *userInputString = @"1990-2020";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\d+)-(\\d+)" options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:userInputString options:NSMatchingReportProgress range:NSMakeRange(0, userInputString.length)];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [userInputString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [userInputString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]]);
}
```

**output:**
1990
2020